# SQL - Sort by column containing smallest value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say I take an image and extract its RGB values resulting into the following table (id, file_name, red_value, green_value, blue_value). Then I run a comparison such that I find the difference in each RGB value and store the result.

I want to sort by the column containing the smallest number. It can be red or green or blue - depends on the dataset used. So how can I implement this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results can really help convey what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
order by least(red_value, green_value, blue_value)
```

This orders by the smallest of the three values.